# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'missingpy'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, data-analysis

When I try to run `from missingpy import KNNImputer` in the conda environment using Jupyter jotebook I get this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b17e25e76e3e> in <module>
----> 1 from missingpy import KNNImputer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'missingpy'
```

I'm using Windows. I tried to get the library in conda they don't have it, but the Python native library has it. How do I install the native Python library?

Comment: After activating the conda environment containing missingpy, how do you start Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: [The Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages) shows how to install non-Conda packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have it?

If you run this you will make sure you have it

```
pip install missingpy
```

If it is still giving errors you are probably in the wrong environment